# Writing bytes to a file in C#

Tags: c#

I have a BLOB from an Oracle database. In .NET it is of type OracleLob and has among them a Read and ReadByte methods.

```
int OracleLob.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
int OracleLob.ReadByte()
```

So the Read method reads a sequence of bytes and ReadByte reads a single byte at a time. Here is my code:

```
OracleLob ol = (OracleLob) cmd.Parameters[1].Value; //her er filen!!

BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@"D:\wordfile.DOCX", FileMode.Create));
int currentByte = ol.ReadByte();

while (currentByte != -1)
{
   binWriter.Write(currentByte);
   currentByte = ol.ReadByte();
}

binWriter.Close();
```

But when I open wordfile.DOCX in Word, it says that the file is corrupt and cannot be opened. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it really a docx file that you should be writing into?

Comment: I think you should try to call Flush() before Close()

Comment: @Volodymyr Usarskyy: `Close` automatically calls `Flush`.

Comment: yes, it's really a DOCX file. In this case it's just a test file and I did manage to write it to a file and open it in Word 2007. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with the code is that it's using an `int` value when writing the byte data to the `BinaryWriter`. It's using the overload that is writing an `int` instead of the one writing a `byte`, so each byte from the source will be written as four bytes. If you check the file size you see that it's four times as large as it should be.

Cast the value to `byte` so that the correct overload of the `Write` method is used:

```
binWriter.Write((byte)currentByte);
```

To do this more efficiently, you can use a buffer to read blocks of bytes instead of a single byte at a time:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(@"D:\wordfile.DOCX", FileMode.Create)) {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  int len = ol.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  while (len > 0) {
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    len = ol.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are exactly right. The file was 4 times as large as expected. I will implement the buffer because it's really slow without it.

Answer (score 3):

`BinaryWriter` will output the int in some form of serialized manner. It won't write just a single byte. Use `FileStream` for this purpose, and use the `byte[]` versions of the read/write methods, since byte-at-a-time streaming is very slow.

Comment: No, it won't write the `int` in some form of serialised manner, it will write it as four plain bytes.

Comment: @Guffa: since it guarantees little-endian format, it *is* a serialization, albeit a trivial one.

Answer (score 2):

A docx file is a OpenXml format file that is basically a series of xml files that is zipped down and renamed to docx. You can't just take a output from a database and write to a file and magically make it into a docx file.

Are you sure it's a docx file you are trying to make here? The only way I can see this working is if you serialized a docx file into the database, but then you have to make sure that it's de-serialized the exactly same way on "the way out", else the underlaying zip file will be corrupt, and the file cannot be opened.

Comment: The database is not mine. I was just told what is put there and thanks to the help from commenters here I did manage to write it to file and open it. I can't tell you whether or not it's the logic way to write a file to a database:-)

Comment: Then it's fine :) If you try to rename the created docx file to a zip file, you can see that it's indeed a zip file with xml files inside it if you want to investigate the format further ;)

Answer (score 1):

currentByte is declared as an int, so the binary writer is writing 4 bytes for each write.

You need to cast currentByte as an actual byte:

```
binWriter.Write((byte) currentByte);
```